# which algorithm is better time complexity?

Tags: performance, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I read about Big-O notation. I understood some idea but when compared two algorithm I don't understood some thing look following
he say existing two algorithm.

```
 First f2(n) = 2n + 20 steps. 
second f3(n) = n + 1 steps.
he write f2 = O(f3):

    f2(n)/f3(n)
    =((2n + 20)/(n + 1))<= 20;
   he say Certainly f3 is better than f2?, of course f3 = O(f2), this time with c = 1.
```

I think f3 is better than f2 because less factors.
my questions

1) why constant c= 1 how he pick that?
2) why f3 = O(f2) and why f2 = O(f3) ?

Answer (score 1):

These are both linear functions, so both are `O(n)`, and both `O` of each other. `f3` is 20 times faster, asymptotically, than `f2`. All these things are simultaneously true.

Answer (score 0):

Patrick87's answer explains a little more about the asymptotic nature of Big-O notation. I will show you a bit more analysis of this. Let's examine `f2` and `f3` a bit more closely:

First, `f2(n)`: We know that `f2(n) = O(2n + 20)`. The 20 is a constant, so we can ignore it. So, `f2(n) = O(2n + 20) = O(2n)`. Again, the 2 is a constant, so we can also ignore it, so: `f2(n) = O(2n + 20) = O(2n) = O(n)`.

What this analysis means is that as `n` increases, a function that is `2n + 20` grows as fast as a function that is `2n`, which grows as fast as a function that is `n`. This makes sense if you think about it: all these functions are parallel lines. Their rate of growth is the same.

Now `f3(n)`: We know that `f3(n) = O(n + 1)`. The 1 is a constant, so we can ignore it. So, `f3(n) = O(n)`.

And that is why `f3` and `f2` are both `O(n)`. This doesn't mean that these functions take the *exact same time* for a given value of `n`, or that `f2` is as fast as `f3` in clock time. It just means that the *complexity* (i.e. the time they take to do work) of both functions increases at the same *rate* as `n` increases.

Comment: Thank you Mr Nik Bougalis your answer useful to me. just remainder some questions. Why he say  (n+1)/(2n+20) this time c = 1. What's benefits from divide f3/f2. Is this method to compared between them?